# Font where if an 8 is rotated 180 degrees it is unchanged

Tags: fonts

In most fonts the “8” is asymmetric - for example, with the upper circle being smaller than the lower one.  I need a font where if you flip the 8 upside down by rotating it 180 degrees what you get  is identical to the unflipped 8.  Anyone know of some fonts where the 8 is designed like this?  Thanks!

Comment: Don't think this will be easy to find – as the number "8" will look top heavy.

What is the use case? Could you alter it manually, or do it have to be "in writing"?

E.g. Adobe Caslon, Big Burro, Briem Akademi have very little difference between the "circles" – might be worth a shot to see how it looks upside down.

My tip would be to flip the text box upside down, then cycle through the fonts you have installed (usually you can use the arrows while in the font select dropdown list). If it looks great upside down, it might not need to be perfect symetrical? Still dependent on use case ...

Comment: The use case is a puzzle where there's a rectangular tray that has an 8 in the center.  There are some pieces in the tray that you need to slide around to surround the 8 in a particular way.  It's impossible to achieve that arrangement unless you rotate the entire puzzle by 180 degrees.  After the rotation the 8 would still be in the center, and it shouldn't look like a slightly different version of the 8 with the top and bottom being slightly different.  It should be identical.

Comment: Since I'm talking about just that one character, I'm thinking of taking the inelegant but practical approach of starting with a nearly rotationally symmetric 8, cutting off its top half and replacing it with its bottom half rotated by 180 degrees.  Offensive to font purists, but at least it gives me what I want.  Even better would be finding a font with a symmetric 8 and not treating some font designer's font so callously.  Hence this post.